# How to include a condition such that the match column gives a blank if the name in raw file is valid but not present in my master file?

Tags: python, r

I have a raw file and a master  file, for example :

raw_file

```
{'resident', 'gulf corp', 'international', 'perl', 'mntain valley'}
```

master_file

```
{'mountain valley', 'gulf corp', 'president', 'national', 'perl'}
```

I want to find the similar strings in both the files. I have used fuzzy.ratio in python.

My output is as follows :

```
resident - president - 98,
gulf corp - gulf corp - 100,
international - national - 85,
perl - perl - 100,
mntain valley - mountain valley - 87

Required output :
resident         
gulf corp - gulf corp - 100,
international     
perl -  perl - 100,
mntain valley - mountain valley -  87
```

Requirement :
When a name in the raw file is meaningful i.e, correct without any spelling mistakes it should check for 100% match if not found it should return empty.

Is there any way to do this?

I gave a thought of restricting the first word but it wouldn't help in cases like

*apple one - aple one*

```
ratio = (fuzz.ratio(str1,str2))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, you could simply check for equality.

```
raw_file = c('resident', 'gulf corp', 'international', 'perl', 'mntain valley')
master_file = c('mountain valley', 'gulf corp', 'president', 'national', 'perl')

df = data.frame(raw=raw_file,master=master_file,
                match=ifelse(raw_file==master_file,"100",""),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
            raw          master match
1      resident mountain valley      
2     gulf corp       gulf corp   100
3 international       president      
4          perl        national      
5 mntain valley            perl
```

If thep position of the words that are the same does not matter, change the `==` for `%in%`

```
> df = data.frame(raw=raw_file,master=master_file,
+                 match=ifelse(raw_file%in%master_file,"100",""),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
            raw          master match
1      resident mountain valley      
2     gulf corp       gulf corp   100
3 international       president      
4          perl        national   100
5 mntain valley            perl
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I also want my code to find the nearest matches, for example, mntain valley to mountain valley  with a matching percentage. But resident should not be matched as it is not present in the master file